# Gradle Task: open port to use as TaskInput

Tags: gradle

Looking to have a task inputs and outputs depending on an open port.

So something like

```
ext {
  serverReady checkPortOpen()
}

task MyTask {
  inputs.property ext.serverReady
  outputs.property ext.serverReady
}
```

Any help or pointers ?

Comment: Output and input properties are seems to be file only according to my understanding. I eagerly await answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by @Opal in the gradle doc, there was a outputs.upToDate that does the job perfectly.

I have a few services to start before running the full tests suite, so I had a :

```
 class BaseServiceTask extends com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.processes.tasks.JavaFork {
    def BaseServiceTask() {
      super()
      classpath project.configurations.all
      args ["-user","user","-password","password","-env","mydevenv"]
    }
 }

 task startServer (type:BaseServiceTask) {
    main = "com.nico.StartServer"
    jvmArgs += ["-Xmx8096m","-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"] // give more memory to data server
    outputs.upToDateWhen { checkSocket(servicePort) } 
    doLast {waitForSocket(servicePort)}
 }
```

And the lower details ...

```
def checkSocket(portS) {
  try {
    new Socket("localhost", portS.toInteger())
    return true 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false
    // throw new GradleScriptException("Required ${portS} is closed", e )
  } 
}

def waitForSocket(portS) {
  while(!checkSocket(portS)) {
    println "Waiting on ${portS}"
    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}
```

Lastly, when running the related gradle task, the output would should the up-to-date status properly:

```
 :startServer UP-TO-DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

As You can see in the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html) for `TaskOutputs` only files can be registered as an output - so no properties here.

When it comes to `TaskInputs` properties can be indeed used and You can find a great example under '$GRADLE_HOME/samples/userguide/tasks/incrementalTask'. Try running:

```
gradle incrementalReverse -PtaskInputProperty=<property>
```

passing same `<property>` several times in a row and then changing. This might be what You're looking for. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#property(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) are requirements for a good property (e.g. being `Serializable`). It seems that You can wrap the state of the port in a property and the used it as an `@Input`.

Comment: You think using upToDateWhen would possible ? http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html#upToDateWhen%28groovy.lang.Closure%29

Comment: It depends what is the purpose exactly, but rather yes.

Comment: @NicolasModrzyk is that what You're looking for?